# How make middle div to fill space between floating elements?

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have three div elements: left, middle and right.
Left and right are fixed and floating. What I want is the **middle div to fill the gap** in between them.

This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <style>
      * {border: dotted 1px red;}
      #left {
         width: 200px;
         float: left;
      }
      #middle {
         float: left;
      }
      #right {
         width: 200px;
         float: right;
      }
   </style>
</head>
<body>
   <div id="left"  >  left   </div>
   <div id="middle">  middle </div>
   <div id="right" >  right  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Any ideas on how to do this? I tried different solutions but didn't manage to do what I want.

Comment: Have you tried converting from `px` to percentages?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

The key is to restructure your html to have `middle` last, remove the `float` from the `middle` and [replace it with `overflow: hidden`](http://web.archive.org/web/20150618153020/http://colinaarts.com/articles/the-magic-of-overflow-hidden/?).

[**View fiddle example.**](http://jsfiddle.net/7BE43/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="left"  >  left   </div>
<div id="right" >  right  </div>
<div id="middle">  middle </div>
```

**CSS**

```
#left {
    width: 200px;
    float: left;
}
#middle {
    overflow: hidden;
}
#right {
    width: 200px;
    float: right;
}
```

Comment: Yo, your link is broken. No chance the article is still available, is there? Also, ballin' and elegant answer. Much apreesh.

Comment: @Thomas Just found an archive of the webpage and swapped the link to that.

Comment: And what if you want 'left' and 'right' element 'wrap content' (like an Android), so 'left' and 'right' consumes as much space as they need during rendering and middle takes the rest? So without predefining the width of the 2 side elements?

Comment: @ktamas It appears as though [it will work](http://jsfiddle.net/mq7evo8r/2/), but obviously if you get too much content, then by the nature of the `float` it will [push stuff _down_](http://jsfiddle.net/mq7evo8r/6/) and [the "middle" is going to ultimately follow after the "right" content because of HTML positioning. So if that is not an issue, it works](http://jsfiddle.net/mq7evo8r/6/).

Comment: @ScottS thanks, but yeah.. this is not good enough for me :)
Right div's bottom should be aligned with left's bottom, so left should go only till right's left side. I will try to do some magic with display: table/table-cell and flex. But thanks anyways :)

Answer (score 3):

I was able to replicate the issue and fix it using percentages instead of absolute values. Since you are looking for something flexible between the two elements this should work.

```
#left {
    width: 20%;
    float: left;
    background: #ccc;
}
#middle {
    width: 60%;
    float: left;
    display: block;
    background: #ddd;
}
#right {
    width: 20%;
    float: right;
    background: #bbb;
}
```

Here's a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vQNaw/2/)

Comment: Thank you. That works but I was wondering if there is a way to do it with a fixed size for the left and right divs.