# overflow-x:hidden "cuts-off" dropdown

Tags: html, css, hover, overflow

Why does adding `overflow-x` to the `header` cause the dropdown item to get "cut-off"?

```css
header {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #336699;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
header li {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
header li:hover .previewImg {
  display: block;
}
header .previewImg {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}
header a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}
.previewImg {
  height: 100px;
  width: 75px;
  background: orange;
  z-index: 999;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Menu Option</a>
      <div class="previewImg">Preview Image Here</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Menu Option</a>
      <div class="previewImg">Preview Image Here</div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</header>
```

I need the `overflow-x` attribute as this dropdown will be included in a DIV which [fills the gap between two floated DIVs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15724700/how-make-middle-div-to-fill-space-between-floating-elements).

I've searched SO and Googled most of the afternoon and am yet to find a solution.  [The desired result](https://jsfiddle.net/6daww16c/).

Comment: since you're using `position:fixed;`, you can use   `top:0;left:0;` and remove that overflow declaration altogether

Answer (score 2):

If the element has `overflow-x: hidden` then `overflow-y` is set to `auto` or other trouble of this kind. See
[CSS overflow-x: visible; and overflow-y: hidden; causing scrollbar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6421966/css-overflow-x-visible-and-overflow-y-hidden-causing-scrollbar-issue)

You should try another way here.