# CSS - overflow: hidden to not cover dropdown

Tags: html, css

I have the following CSS and HTML:

```css
body { background-color: #c0c0c0; }
.title-bar, { background-color: #999; color: white; float: left; overflow: hidden; }
.title-bar {
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
  height: 128px;
  width: 100%;
}
.logo, .user-info { box-sizing: content-box; height: 100%; width: 128px; }
.logo{
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #369;
  border-right: 1px solid white;
  display: flex;
  float: left;
  font-size: 2em;
  font-kerning: none;
  justify-content: center;
}
.user-info {
  align-items: center;
  border-left: 1px solid white;
  display: flex;
  float: right;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
}
.user-info .circle {
  border: 2px solid #369;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  height: 32px;
  margin: 8px 8px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: border 0.15s ease-out;
  width: 32px;
}
.user-info .circle:hover { border-width: 4px; }
.user-info .container {
  border-top: 1px solid white;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 6px;width: 100%;
}
.hor-nav { background-color: #404040; }
.option { display: inline-block; position: relative; }
.hor-nav .option:hover {background-color: #369; }
.option a {
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 1em;
  padding: 14px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: background-color 0.15s ease-out;
}
.option .dropdown { display: none; position: absolute; }
.option:hover .dropdown{ display: block; }
.dropdown a {
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="title-bar">
  <a class="logo" href="#">
  </a>
  <div class="user-info">
    <a href="#" class="circle"></a>
    <span>User name</span>
    <div class="container">
      <a href="#" class="circle"></a>
      <a href="#" class="circle"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="hor-nav">
    <div class="option">
      <a href="">OPTION 1</a>
      <div class="dropdown">
        <a href="#">ITEM 1</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

as you can see, the `hor-nav` bar's color spills onto the `user-info` area.

I have researched this and found that if I set `overflow-x: hidden;` it will not do this (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15724700/how-make-middle-div-to-fill-space-between-floating-elements) article).

I have tried that and it is true - the nav bar does not spill into the `user-info` but, when you hover over one of the nav bar `options`, the `dropdown` does not come down but instead the `vert-nav` gives you a scroll bar (see [this](https://jsfiddle.net/bqpnyhdr/) jsfiddle).

Additionally, if you do `overflow-y: hidden;` there is no scroll bar at all.

**I am trying to get it so that the `background-color` of the `hor-nav` does not spill into other div's, but also allows the `dropdown` to be activated and work**

thank you.

Comment: You floated user-info, so it's (mostly) removed from document flow calculations. That lets the hor-nav expand to the full available space, which INCLUDES the space occupied by your user-info - user-info's not included in the width calculations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to to this with least code change is to just give the `user-info` area a background color. Since the `hor-nav` section is lower on the z-index this will give the visual affect you want although the bar will still be under the `user-info` section it won't appear to be and the drop down will funtion as it does now.

Per your inquiry, you could do this another way by using percentage based widths for all 3 elements so they don't overlap eachother. Please see this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bqpnyhdr/5/) for code change (note I change the markup order slightly, widths, and added box sizing css property)

Comment: thank you. yes I had thought about this but was apprehensive in applying this as it would mean setting the same background-color twice (I know - think of all the micro-seconds wasted - but right now there is a big push where I am to have the least amount of wasteful code possible). If this is the only way then I will do it, but maybe there is another way?

Comment: @4lackof - yes, I added another way of doing it. Please see my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

The way I see it, you have 3 options

1. You can try adding margin-left/right to the `hor-nav`.

   `.hor-nav {
     margin: auto 128px;
   }`
2. Another option is to set a certain width to the `.hor-nav`. Or practically cut the width of it.

   `.hor-nav {
     width: calc(100% - 128px);
   }`
3. And third, is to add a background color to the `.user-info`